# Cómo guardar permutaciones como string separados por líneas en archivo de texto plano con python

Tags: python, itertools

Tengo este código python para generar permutaciones y guardarlas en arhivo de texto:

```
archivo=open('permutaciones.txt', 'w')
import itertools  
permutaciones = itertools.permutations('darcehe', 6) 
archivo.write("%s\n"%'\n'.join(map(str, permutaciones)))
archivo.close()
```

Pero obtengo:

> ('e', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'r')
>
> ('e', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'd', 'a')
>
> ('e', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'd', 'c')

Y necesito obtener:

> eheacr
>
> eherda
>
> eherdc

una permutación en cada línea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se itera con cadenas de caracteres es frecuente obtener tuplas. Hay que hacer un `"".join()` para crear la cadena:

```py
import itertools  

permutaciones = itertools.permutations('darcehe', 6) 

with open('permutaciones.txt', 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.writelines("".join(p)+"\n" for p in permutaciones)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Resuelto